# Application stopping on clicking submit button with asp-page-handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, model-binding

I have two forms in a RazorPage

This is Form 1

```
<form method="post" >
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="Member.USER_ID" />
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label lead" asp-for="Member.EMAIL">
                                        Email
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                                <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-1x"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <input asp-for="Member.EMAIL" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                    <Span class="text text-danger" asp-validation-for="Member.EMAIL"></Span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label lead" asp-for="Member.PASSWORD">
                                        Password
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                                <i class="fa fa-lock fa-1x"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="password" asp-for="Member.PASSWORD" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                    <Span class="text text-danger" asp-validation-for="Member.PASSWORD"></Span>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" asp-page-handler="Member" value="Member">Log In</button>
                            </form>
```

This is Form 2

```
<form method="post" >
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="Admin.ADMIN_ID" />
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label lead" asp-for="Admin.EMAIL">
                                        Email
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                                <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-1x"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <input asp-for="Admin.EMAIL" class="form-control" />
                                        <Span class="text text-danger" asp-validation-for="Admin.EMAIL"></Span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label class="control-label lead" asp-for="Admin.PASSWORD">
                                        Password
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                                <i class="fa fa-lock fa-1x"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="password" asp-for="Admin.PASSWORD" class="form-control" />
                                        <Span class="text text-danger" asp-validation-for="Admin.PASSWORD"></Span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" style="background-color:cornflowerblue" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" asp-page-handler="Admin" value="Admin">Sign In</button>
                            </form>
```

and this is the PageModel for this razor page

```
public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IAppData appData;

        [BindProperty]
        public Admin Admin { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public Member Member { get; set; }

        public LoginModel(IAppData appData)
        {
            this.appData = appData;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            
        }

        public IActionResult OnPostAdminAsync()
        {
            return Page();
        }

        public IActionResult OnPostMemberAsync()
        {
            
            return RedirectToPage("./Dashboard",null);
        }
    }
```

The problem is whenever I click any of the two-button the applications stop and debugging is stopped.

I have tried changing the position of `asp-page-helper="Admin"` to and from Form tag and Button tag many times but no luck.

What can be the solution for this?

Comment: You mean it crashes? Enable break on all exceptions and see what the problem is.

Comment: It is already enabled.

Comment: You can clean and rebuild the project,then try again?